# google maps insertAt

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In V3 of the javascript api for the polygon array there is a function `insertAt()`, does anyone have an example of how this is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your MVCArray object:

```
pathCoords = new google.maps.MVCArray();
```

Then set up your map:

```
myPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: pathCoords,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
myPoly.setMap(map);
```

You can then insert `latLng` objects:

```
myPoly.getPath().insertAt(pathCoordinates.length, latLng);
```

Comment: My pleasure Paul.. also notice I corrected a mistake - `pathCoords` should be declared before the map. But I guess that's not where you were stuck, anyway.

Comment: The documentation does not make clear whether insertAt inserts *before* or *after* the specified index.  I need to insert *before* the first element, so I assume index 0 would work?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#MapTypeInterface

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay.html